Api gateway invoking a lambda returns 403
I've recently migrated a local python script to lambda via aws cdk. It collects data from an public api endpoint. On my local machine this function works 100% of the time when it comes to status codes and responses from the api.
When the code is running within the lambda alone its also working fine, 100% of requests are returning with 200.
When the lambda is invoked by an api gateway it will fail with a 403?
Other info

api is public and requires no auth
all deployed with AWS CDK 2
gateway has no issues accessing the lambda as the debugging comes back correctly formatted
Lambda works with HTTP 200 when testing via console
API Gateway fails with 403 when testing via the console
API Gateway fails with 403 when testing via curl on local machine


You should provide more information; e.g. how is the service deployed (serverless framework), how is it configured, does the API gateway have the IAM rights to invoke the Lambda... Does it work, when you make a test request in the AWS console / API gateway?

I mean, the change in return status code should imply most of the above as irrelevant. Ive added the context requested regarding deployments and responses from testing.

"gateway has no issues accessing the lambda as the debugging comes back correctly formatted" and "API Gateway fails with 403 when testing via the console" don't make sense to me. If it fails, how can you be sure, that the gateway has no issues? What's the output in the AWS console, when you get the 403?

The api gateway invokes a lambda. The lambda calls the api with 200 shown in cloud watch logs.
When run via the apigateway the logs show 403 from the same host.

Sorry, I don't get what you mean. There are two APIs? When does what fail under which circumstances? Try to describe the flow precisely.

EDIT: This is likely very unhelpful for the masses and is basically user error at this point.
In this case my internal lambda logic was causing an occasional malforming to happen one of the parameters within shared scripts.
This caused the 3rd party during processing to inconsistently return 403.
Still unsure why this always worked on local tho....
